# OTA is only available for enterprise account?

Tags: ios, ota

I have an apple individual account($99). Is it possible to let my client test the app by OTA? Thanks. I mean just give him a link http://www.xxxx.com/app.html

Comment: You might have to add his device to your account and send him the ipa file to install it using iTunes.

Comment: I mean just give him a link http://www.aaabbb.com/app.html, is this possible?

Comment: You might need an enterprise account. check https://testflightapp.com/. Alternatively you can try loading your ipa file to some server and check if it is showing install screen when you access the url from iPhone safari. I am not sure if this work with dev profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a service like [Testflight](http://testflightapp.com/). They use OTA with AdHoc provisioning for installing, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you need the [UDID](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/08/08/iphone-101-find-udid-with-a-single-click/) of your client's device, add it to your provisioning profile and send him/her the ipa and the provisioning profile. He/She then can "install" both files on the device using either [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/de/itunes/) or [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) ([Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466)).